# Not detecting any wireless

Tags: wireless

I just installed 10.10 on Dell, http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201011-6891 along with Widows 7.

However it does not detect any wireless, so I am not able to connect to internet.

Wireless works on windows 7.

I have added my wireless connection but it does not work either. 
If I connect a cable, it works through Auto eth0.

What is wrong and how can I fix the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System > Administration > Additional Drivers and see if you have a disabled proprietary driver. If any error occurs during enabling of proprietary driver go to Synaptic Package Manager and search for broadcom or bcm. There are lots of alternative. In my case `bcmwl-kernel-source` package worked. I also recommend you to see as well as paste which wireless card you have with `lspci | grep wireless`. Be sure to stay wired during this.

Comment: centrino adcanced-N 6205. I will try and let you know.

Comment: I installed bcmwl-kernl-source, but it does not work. lspci | grep wireless does not return anything.

Comment: it doesnot work with centrino. Its for broadcom. Since you have intel centrino you should search for centrino drivers not broadcom. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WiFiHowTo See if you could find your hardware here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing WICD as an alternative to network manager. Many people find network manager simply does not work. I have never had wifi working with network manager but WICD has always solved the issue for me. WICD has limitations in that it does not handle public wifi or VPN but for home and work wifi it is very good.

Plug in your cable and install WICD from the software centre.

The type the following in the terminal

sudo apt-get remove network-manager
sudo /etc/init.d/wicd restart

If this does not solve your problem I am out of my depth.

Comment: Recommending another piece of software without identifying the issue is a terrible solution IMHO.